# Proof of lemma 15.40 in Jech

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm stuck in the following proof:

[image]

First, should it say $G_\alpha=G\cap X_\alpha$ instead of $G\cap\overline{X_\alpha}$?

Also, in the inductive clause for $G_\alpha$, does Jech mean
$$
G_\alpha=\left\{ a\in X_\alpha: \exists Z\ \exists \beta<\alpha \left[a=\sum Z\wedge Z\cap (G_\beta\cup\overline{G_\beta})\neq\emptyset\right]\right\}?
$$
If so, I'm not sure how to get that $G_\alpha$ actually equals that. Namely, if $a=\sum Z$ for some $Z\subset\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}X_\beta\cup\overline{X_\beta}$, how can we modify $Z$ to get it to meet some $G_\beta\cup\overline{G_\beta}$?

Comment: For the first question, quite clearly, yes, this is a typo.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Okay, I was quite sure that was the case, but wanted to check just in case. The last question is the more interesting one

Comment: Clearly... :-))

Comment: If $Z\subseteq\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}(X_\beta\cup\overline{X_\beta})$ but $Z$ meets neither $G_\beta$ nor $\overline{G_\beta}$, then $Z$ is disjoint from $G$, and therefore $\sum Z\notin G$ because $G$ is generic.

Comment: @AndreasBlass got it, thanks!